# Python pywebview. Проблемы с pythonnet - Необработанное исключение: System.NullReferenceException. TypeError: 'Assembly' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, webview, pythonnet

```
import webview
webview.create_window('Hello world', 'https://pywebview.flowrl.com/hello')
webview.start()
```

При выполнении выдаёт:

```
Необработанное исключение: System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
в System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_CacheTextInternal ()
в System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Text()
в System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Text(String value)
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatch Info.Throw()
в Python.Runtime.PythonException.ThrowLastAsClrExcep tion()
в Python.Runtime.Dispatcher.TrueDispatch(Object[] args)
в Python.Runtime.Dispatcher.Dispatch(Object[] args)
в __System_Threading_ThreadStartDispatcher.Invoke()
в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(Exec utionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionCon text executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionCon text executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
в System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Выше упомянутая проблема решается установкой pythonnet 3.0.0a2, но теперь выдаёт:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio Code\Python Projects\webviewTest.py", line 3, in <module>
webview.start()
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pytho n39\lib\site-packages\webview\__init__.py", line 122, in start
guilib = initialize(gui)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pytho n39\lib\site-packages\webview\guilib.py", line 101, in initialize
if not try_import(guis):
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pytho n39\lib\site-packages\webview\guilib.py", line 62, in try_import
if import_func():
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pytho n39\lib\site-packages\webview\guilib.py", line 52, in import_winforms
import webview.platforms.winforms as guilib
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pytho n39\lib\site-packages\webview\platforms\winforms.py", line 31, in <module>
import clr
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pytho n39\lib\site-packages\clr.py", line 6, in <module>
load()
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pytho n39\lib\site-packages\pythonnet\__init__.py", line 42, in load
func = _LOADER_ASSEMBLY["Python.Runtime.Loader.Initialize"]
TypeError: 'Assembly' object is not subscriptable
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно сделать, как мне использовать pywebview?

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент, для корректной работы pywebview, надо использовать: pythonnet 3.0.0a2 и clr-loader 0.1.7:

```
pip install pythonnet==3.0.0a2
pip install clr-loader==0.1.7
```

Решение нашёл [здесь](https://github.com/r0x0r/pywebview/issues/952)